# Composer - Clone Git Repository (Bitbucket) On Pipeline With Username and Password (Without SSH Keys) in DockerFile

Tags: git, docker, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a `composer.json` file which checks out two private Bitbucket repositories which I am building in Docker.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:repo/service.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:repo/package.git"
    }
]
```

Currently, the only way I can get this to work, is by injecting the SSH key into the image so it can pull the private repositories. This in turn, requires us to check-in the key into SCM which is not ideal (and a pretty bad practice overall).

```
ADD ./build_id_rsa /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
ADD ./build_id_rsa.pub /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Referencing the documentation, it looks like SSH keys are the only supported option - https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories.

> The only requirement is the installation of SSH keys for a git client.

My hope is that there is a way to authenticate via username and password which I can pass in with Bitbucket repository variables which you can secure.

I will also take any other workaround that others have come up with to build a Docker image that runs `composer install` which checks out private git repositories.

Comment: If one of the answers to your question is correct you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with composer but here is an option i can think of that might help you.

Create a base image with the ssh key  and store the image in a private docker registry
Then strat every build from the image with the key already in it, this way you don't have to save the key in source control.

Also you not even have to use this image actually you can use docker multi stage build and copy the key from the base image to any image you want to use this way you can still build with any docker image you want and have the not from source control.

P.S.
There is option in bitbucket to authenticate using username and password in the url like below.
`https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git`
Maybe this could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to bake the key into the container - you can add the private key in Pipelines, in the repo admin panel.

The process looks a little like this:

1. Go to the repo admin panel and click the "SSH keys" link.
2. Add an existing private key, or have Pipelines generate a 2048-bit RSA key for you.
3. If you're using a key that Pipelines generated, then copy the public key; if you're using an existing key, then copy its public key. Add the copied key to the `service` and `package` repos as an "access key" (in the "Access keys" screen on those repos' admin panels).
4. Have the bitbucket-pipelines.yml use SSH as normal. The key in the SSH keys screen will be the default key for connection attempts; Bitbucket already knows its own host key fingerprint, so you won't have to update known_hosts, and the access key setup provides read-only access to the repo without burning a user seat.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html is the documentation for this.

Comment: This was the ideal solution which I did try but didn't work for my use case. I believe the reason why is because the pipeline itself is not calling `composer`. It is actually the `docker build` container (within the pipeline container) that is doing this work which doesn't have access to the keys. I have tested and can run `composer` on the pipeline directly outside of a `docker build.`